# What are the differences between the Deadpool movie and the leaked script?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Several years ago, before Deadpool was greenlit, its script leaked online. I recently remember one of the producers recently saying in an interview that the final movie was 30% different. Which parts changed?

### What are the differences between the Deadpool movie and its leaked script?

Comment: This [article on io9](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-makers-of-deadpool-had-to-slash-7-million-from-the-1758147495) talks about some last-minute change to the script in order to significantly reduce the budget, so that the project could be greenlit: some action scenes were scrapped / simplified and a few characters "condensed" into a single one (I personally haven't read the leaked script or watched the movie, just found the article and thought it could be a useful link).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deadpool writers *Rhett Reese* and *Paul Wernick* recently revealed that they had to trim $7 million from the budget before officially being given the green light by the studio bosses at Fox who were so reluctant to make the movie a reality, and among the casualties of those cutbacks were two major action sequences. Other than that, there were some cut-outs because producers thought them unnecessary.

1. An elaborate motorbike chase involving dozens of other vehicles which was set to feature Deadpool and Ajax racing across the freeway before ending up inside a house being transported on the back of a lorry. When they are inside the house, two characters exchange blows in pretty much every room before the truck turns over and things wrap up just like the movie with Deadpool pinning Francis to the freeway with one of his katanas.
2. The old aircraft carrier was actually another building which was the setting for a massive – and very violent – gunfight which goes on for pages and pages in the screenplay. That scene also ends with Deadpool using the bodies to spell out “*FRANCIS*” when he’s done.
3. Rhett Reese (screen writer) has also admitted that Wade leaving his guns behind in the taxi was added in order to completely cut these scenes out, replacing them instead with that still very good (but much cheaper) sword fighting sequence.
4. Wade wilson (Deadpool) vs. Wolverine panned out differently. Hugh Jackman never ends up making a physical appearance as Wolverine (*other than Deadpool stapling that magazine cover to his face, he’s never referenced in the script either*). However, he’s referenced a fair few times, and had things progressed differently, another Marvel superhero would have been making their presence felt in this movie.
5. Creation of Deadpool's suit. When Wade is creating his superhero suit, he’s shown (in the script) in a costume store looking through a box of masks, one of which just happens to be a Spider-Man one. Staring at it for a moment, he turns it inside out and the sees that the interior of the mask is obviously plain red with black around the eyes. With that, the script points out that he “smirks” as “inspiration has struck.” Deadpool and Spider-Man are two characters who share a fair bit of history in the comic books, but two characters has different studios making their films. Holywood sucks.
   Whether that would have prohibited Wade from using one of Spider-Man masks as a prop is hard to say, but the movie ended up going with an entirely different montage to explain how Wade went about creating his costume.
6. Angel Dust isn’t included in the original draft of Deadpool, and surprisingly, there’s also no sign of Negasonic Teenage Warhead (when Colossus goes after and later teams up with Wade, he’s alone both times). Yet another result of the reduced budget, Angel was actually the replacement for a trio of villains from the comic books; Garrison Kane, Sluggo, and Wyre, all of whom would have worked for Ajax as orderlies of a sort.
7. In the movie, Wade pretty much resigns himself to his fate upon learning that he’s dying of cancer, but in the screenplay, he tried pretty much everything to save himself before accepting the offer of that mysterious Mr. Smith look-a-like. He travels the world trying to find a cure for himself but things get violent when he arrived Mexico to meet a doctor who claims he can remove people’s tumours. Upon learning that he’s actually ripping people off by revealing they’re “cured” after showing them what is in reality chicken guts, Wade brutally murders him, holding the doctor’s still beating heart in his hands.
8. After Mexico and Wade’s escape from Ajax’s facility, Wade tries to kill himself a few times in a brutal suicide fashion only to discover he is immortal. These are not included in the movie.
9. Screenplay represents a very easy-going and likable Wade when movie starts with Wade and that stalker pizza-guy.
10. Ajax’s real name being Francis is an even bigger deal in the screenplay and Wade’s obsession with taunting his captor about that leads to him carving something on his forehead during their battle in the facility he’s being kept in. What that is isn’t revealed to the audience until much later in the movie when he pays a visit to Weasel’s bar.
    It’s there that we see Wade carved “Hello, My Name Is Franchise” onto his forehead, and it’s tough to say why they decided against including this.
11. Screenplay which was written in 2010 has Amy Winehouse in *Dead Pool* but since the artist's tragic death in 2011, they did not include this in the movie.
12. The song that plays while Wade is sitting on the bridge, drawing. It was originally "Holla Back Girl" but changed later in the movie to "Shoop."

[You can find the leaked script here if you want to take a look.](http://www.slideshare.net/zacharygoldrich/deadpool-movie-leaked-script-1)

Comment: I seem to recall there having been more scenes about Ikea in the script.