# How does Deadpool escape his torture chamber?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the incredible *Deadpool* movie, we get to see how Wade Wilson becomes Deadpool. For the final stage of his transformation, he is fastened into a glass/metal chamber by his neck, arms, and I assume legs as well. Once he mutates, he attempts to escape the chamber by igniting the oxygen supply (which btw, doesn't work because oxygen is not a fuel, it is only an oxidizer, but I won't get into that). He successfully leaves the chamber, before losing a fight and remaining to burn with the entire facility.

**I am wondering how he ever escaped the chamber?** The glass seemed pretty thick and he was fastened in pretty well. I thought well maybe he broke out, but that's probably not true, because those chambers were designed to hold even stronger mutants like Angel Dust. Plus, if he was strong enough to break out, why cause the fire in the first place? Just break out and breach the part of the lab where Francis is.

Then I thought maybe some debris broke his chamber and he escaped. However, this is also unlikely because the debris would not just randomly break through and cut his straps without taking pieces of his body (he seemed to be whole when he got out, and his regen isn't very fast). Also, if debris could break it then other mutants should have been able to get out and it's likely they would have attacked Francis.

Comment: the intent is that the explosion blew the tank open, however unlikely you think that would be. I doubt there's a better answer.

Comment: The scene in question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaMwbx4qFpA The first clear shot of the chamber we get post-explosion shows the glass is broken, and it certainly wasn't broken before the explosion, so that's probably your answer.

Comment: It's also possible the explosion destroyed only his restraints and he had to break the glass himself once his arms were free, though I'm not sure how we could prove it one way or the other.

Comment: At this point I am chalking it up to a continuity mistake, I think it's really unlikely that (a) the explosion destroyed **only** his chamber in a perfect way for him to escape or (b) that he had the strength to break out all along.

Comment: @MBarbosa: “I think it's really unlikely that (a) the explosion destroyed only his chamber in a perfect way for him to escape” — you’re saying that the explosion of the gas *feeding into his chamber* probably wouldn’t have destroyed his chamber? Uh huh.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite no I'm sure it had enough energy, but if you read the text under my question, I state that it is unlikely that the explosion blew the glass and the 3-5 things strapping him down perfectly without taking parts of his body out. If it had dismembered him in any way we would have seen results of it when he fought Francis (given that his regen is a little slow).

Comment: @MBarbosa: sure. It’s just that *that’s what happened in the movie*. Was it less unlikely than everything else that happened?

Comment: @MBarbosa It might be worth asking another question about whether Deadpool has been blown up in the comics and what it did to his body/how long it took him to recover. Personally I can easily imagine him surviving that explosion with only a few seconds of recovery time, but there's probably a bigger comic book nerd here somewhere who can prove which of us is right about that.

Comment: @Ixrec he has regenerated from just his head multiple times, but I don't know how long it took. Although in the movie he cuts off his own hand and goes through at least a few hours of regen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast/director commentary track for Deadpool indicates that the match was the sole means of his escape:

> **Reese:** ***I like the fact that you got out by virtue of this match.*** I think a lot of times, as screenwriter you're trying to get your
>   protagonist locked into a box, and then figure out how to get them
>   out in a way that's not totally obvious. And **we planted that match in
>   the mouth of Angel Dust, always with the intent of having it be the
>   device that Wade used to get out of the Punch Bowl.** That's kind of
>   cool.
>
> **Reynolds:** *Yeah, I always loved that too. That was a nice plant pay-off as you call it.*

[image]

As you can see, the Punch Bowl impacts the floor at at least 50fps, propelled by the force of the explosion. It's quite reasonable to assume that the restraints would break when combined with Wade's weight and the pressure that he's exerting on them. Additionally, the flames and the explosion itself could have damaged the leather straps or the buckles.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the leaked shooting script, **the explosion destroyed the "Punch Bowl" torture chamber**.

[image]

Specifically these lines:

> ...the TANK EXPLODES.
>   The Punch Bowl is BLOWN APART, and the frame of the hospital
>   bed SNAPS in TWO.

It doesn't *explicitly* say "blown apart because of the explosion", but it seems pretty clear that was the intent.

For completeness, [the leaked script is not identical to the final movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118427/what-are-the-differences-between-the-deadpool-movie-and-the-leaked-script), but as far as I know there were no major changes to this particular scene. The most significant change that's relevant to this question is that the movie includes a shot of Ajax turning to see the chamber broken and empty before Deadpool attacks him.

[image]
<sub>Screenshot taken from [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaMwbx4qFpA)</sub>

At the very least, this proves that in the final movie Deadpool got himself out of the chamber after the glass was broken. It's conceivable that Deadpool had to break the glass himself after the explosion, but I don't know of any reason to believe the explosion didn't break it.